# Explain operation of solid-state relay

Tags: relay, opto-isolator

![CPC1230N
Single-Pole, Normally Open
4-Pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXrJM.png)

Link for Datasheet:

http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/CPC1230N.pdf/$file/CPC1230N.pdf

This is the relay I am using in my circuit, but I am not getting how it connects/disconnects and flow of i/p. ( It has two control i/p's and two load pins )

Please explain its operation.

Comment: Thanks expressed in a question are neither necessary nor desired. You can show your thanks by up-voting answers you find useful/informative and by accepting the one you find to be the best after waiting a reasonable amount of time for the possible flurry of answers to die down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relay is constructed from an infrared LED which is optically coupled to the paralleled light-sensitive gates of an N channel and a P channel enhancement mode MOSFET with their channels wired in series.

**CORRECTION:**

The relay is constructed from an infrared LED which is optically coupled to the paralleled light-sensitive gates of two N channel enhancement mode MOSFETs with their channels wired source-to source in series opposition.

When the LED illuminates the MOSFETS it enhances their channels, causing the resistance of the relay's output to fall to a low value, and when the LED is extinguished the resistance across the output terminals will rise to a high value.

Consequently, with enough current flowing through the LED the relay will be turned ON, and with no current through the LED the relay will be turned off.

Unlike a common magnetically operated relay, the actuating current is unipolar, but like a common magnetically operated relay, the current through the MOSFET "contacts" may be either direct or alternating.

Comment: I think there's a detector chip that uses photovoltaic diodes to generate the gate voltage and an active turn- off circuit. In other words, that internal diagram is greatly simplified. I'm using some parts that work with external MOSFETs.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: OK, thanks. Can you post a link to the parts, please?  They sound handy. :-)

Comment: [Here](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0259EN) is one- IXSYS has some too but they're listed as non stock. Also Panasonic and Vishay. Not the one I'm working with- kind of special requirements for that - 4K operation (Brrr).